# javascript funciton not being called

Tags: onclick

What's wrong in below code. It is not calling the function. After clicking compare it does not do anything. Function is not being called.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
          <input type="text" name="hash1" id="Hash1" placeholder="Enter First MD5" required>
          <input type="text" name="hash2" id="Hash2" placeholder="Enter 2nd MD5" required>
          <input type="button" value="Compare" onclick="myfn(); return false;" />

<script>
  function myfn(){
  document.write("Hello There");
  hash1 = document.write(document.getElementsByName("hash1")[0].value;
  hash2 = document.write(document.getElementsByName("hash2")[0].value;
  action_src = hash1 + "/" + hash2;
  document.write(acton_src);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are spelling (`action_src != acton_src`), syntax (missing parentheses), and logical errors (`document.write()` does not return a value) in your code. After you fix those, maybe we can take a look at any remaining problems you might be having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing some closing parenthesis on the hash variable definitions.

hash1 = document.write(document.getElementsByName("hash1")[0].value **)** ;
hash2 = document.write(document.getElementsByName("hash2")[0].value **)** ;

Also, I don't see why you need to return false on this line:
onclick="myfn(); return false;"

There is also a spelling error.
action_src = hash1 + "/" + hash2;
document.write(act**i**on_src);

Comment: Good Catch. How I missed that. Corrected these two added closing ) and spelling.  It did called the function this time and only first write executed. That last write did not.

Comment: not able to find out reason for not writing that last write.

Comment: According to [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write),   
The syntax is: document.write(markup).    
maybe try putting the string in <h2> tags?
document.write("<h2> " + action_src + "</h2>")

Comment: You should definitely check the error output in the dev tools. While viewing the page, press CTRL + SHIFT + i  then click on the Console tab.

Comment: Thank you!. I will check further on this. It had other issue in my code. I was using document.write and also assigning to variable. Not sure if that matters or not. But it still did not work after removing document.write. 
However, I tried using button tag, instead of input and type button. For whatever reason, it worked. I am sure, some silly mistake from me only. I will check further later. Thank you for your help.